# How do I add a base target="_self" to my Joomla site's header?

Tags: joomla, head

I'm trying to add a simple base `target="_self"` to my Joomla! 2.5 site's head HTML file. Where do I find that? Thanks!

Comment: can I ask you why? that's the default.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla! uses templates to format it's pages, it comes with several pre-installed and you can [install a new template](http://docs.joomla.org/Installing_a_template) from various libraries or by [creating a template](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template).

You will need to look in the directory `/templates/your-template/` where `your-template` is the name of your active template.

Depending on the complexity of the template you may find the head section in the `index.php` file or in an included sub-file.